# Display contact information by clicking on the mobile number

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have a mobile number and I am able to detect that mobile number with relevant contacts but how to take user to see the contact details via default contact application in android.

i.e.

**If he clicks the mobile number it should take him to the contact page in phone application.**

Suppose if 999999999 is there in phone contacts then after clicking it, it should take him to the contacts page(Default by phone).

How to achieve this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to call the intent with ACTION_VIEW, but you will need the contact ID before hand...

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contactID));
    intent.setData(uri);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

**Edit:**

To get a contact id from contact number:

```
public static int getContactIDFromNumber(String contactNumber,Context context)
{
    contactNumber = Uri.encode(contactNumber);
    int phoneContactID = new Random().nextInt();
    Cursor contactLookupCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.contactNumber),new String[] {PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);
        while(contactLookupCursor.moveToNext()){
            phoneContactID = contactLookupCursor.getInt(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup._ID));
            }
        contactLookupCursor.close();

    return phoneContactID;
}
```

For more on Contact manipulation, have a look at this [answer...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10977926/2219600)

Comment: how to get contact id

Comment: I am getting error here `Uri.contactNumber` in 5th line of your code